# WPF C# string to decimal, decimal to string problem

Tags: c#, wpf, string, decimal

Please, help me to identify problem in my C# code(WPF, event-handler):

```
        private void Discount5Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal catPr;
        decimal salePr;
        string catPrStr;
        catPrStr = PriceCatTBox.Text;
        catPr = decimal.Parse(catPrStr);
        salePr = decimal.Multiply(catPr, 0.95m);
        SalePriceTBox.Text = (salePr).ToString("0000.00");
    }
```

I can not make it work - debugger shows error on `catPr = decimal.Parse(catPrStr);` . Very similar code in another place works. And am I right in such an approach to string-decimal conversion for arithmetic operation?

**Edit (added)**

Sorry for not specifying  `catPrStr` value, it is from textbox in the following code (in another event-handler):

```
dlg.PriceCatTBox.Text = "2300.00";
....
```

and then as above:

```
catPrStr = PriceCatTBox.Text;
```

Comment: ok.. and what is the value of catPrStr variable?

Comment: thanks, I have added content about "catPrStr" variable in my initial question as edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your culture (locale) settings aren't interfering? If `catPrStr` is always in the invariant culture shown in your edited question, you could use `decimal.TryParse(catPrStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` to force the usage of that culture. If the culture isn't specified, parsing is done in the current system culture, which might, for example, use a comma as the decimal separator.

Comment: I didn't manage to implement the code with suggested "TryParse" method, but the problem was in commas indeed. After I change "dlg.PriceCatTBox.Text = "2300.00";" to .."2300,00".. everything worked OK. Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you hard-code the value like that, it will fail in some other culture. You might want to use for example `dlg.PriceCatTBox.Text = 2300.00.ToString("0.00")` instead.

Answer (score 3):

> And am I right in such an approach to
>   string-decimal conversion for
>   arithmetic operation?

I would set up two way binding with a model to store your decimal values. This will allow you to access them directly instead of parsing strings. This will also solve your error.

Comment: WPF has many hooks for data binding and will make this relatively trivial.

Comment: +1 WPF data binding and the MVVM pattern is designed to remove the necessity to do these kinds of conversions manually

Answer (score 1):

We can't help you because we don't know the value of `catPrStr`, you are converting from `String` to `Decimal` and most likely the value of the string being converted is incorrect.

Comment: thanks, I have added content about "catPrStr" variable in my initial question

Answer (score 1):

`decimal.TryParse(catPrStr, out catPr);` and handle the bool return from it to ensure that you have a reasonable value to process.